# Canvas ctx.drawImage is not working with a transparent PNG

Tags: html5-canvas

ctx.drawImage() is not working when I use a transparent PNG, but does work when I use a regular PNG.

```
 var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
 ....
 function draw(img, x, y){
   context.drawImage(img, x, y);
 }

 //actulaly there is loop here, but for simplicity I put only this.
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "images/a.png";
 img.onload = draw(img, 10, 10);
```

If I use a regular PNG image it works, but with a PNG with transparency that has the background deleted, it is not working. 
Do you guys have any idea why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.onload` takes a function reference rather than a function call.

So do this:

```
img.onload=function(){draw(img,10,10);}
```

If you need to load many images, here is an image preloader that fully loads all images before calling the start() function:

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push all your image urls!
imageURLs.push("");
imageURLs.push("");

// the loaded images will be placed in images[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```

Comment: Still not working. Function draw() was called 11550 times (I have a console.log there) but it drew nothing. Interesting is that there is no error in the Console either. If I use another PNG file without transparency it does work.

Comment: Ahhh...11500 times through the loop...OK, if `var img` is inside a loop, then it's likely that the next interation of the loop will replace `img` before the the first iteration of `img` has fully loaded.  So be sure the next iteration of your loop doesn't execute before the first onload is completed.  Probably unrelated, but put .onload before .src (just in case).

Comment: Yes, it is in a loop. You may be right, because now that "var img" is in the loop, it is not working neither with the image it did work before. I'll make a try, thank you.

Comment: I added an image preloader to my answer. If you use that, you're guaranteed that the images are fully loaded before you draw them. ;-)

Comment: Thank you!!!! That was the root of the problem. I put the "var img = new Image(); img.onload = function(){ draw(); }"  out of the loop and ... voila, it worked. Thank you !!

Comment: Thank you also for the code provided. Yes, this was the issue, I needed to draw many different images. Thank you for the code.

Comment: Thank you very much markE. Now I understand the true value of your code. I was not familiar with the callback concept, as I come from java background.